# What is a virtualized directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-virtualization

Installation of some IBM products on Windows 7 gives me this warning.

"To run the application without administrative privileges on Windows 7 operating system, you must install the application package into a directory that is not virtualized. The Program Files directory on Windows 7 is virtualized."

What does a virtualized directory mean?

I am assuming here it implies virtualization using Microsoft virtualization technologies.

If I use other virtualization technologies such as VMWare does this warning make any sense?

Comment: I am not sure why it is off topic. I noticed this message when I was installing IBM Software and it was not evident whether this referred to virtualization or something else. Thanks to Martins' answer I have a better understanding of what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtualized directory redirects write attempts to a hidden folder in the user profile if the user does not have write access to the directory itself (think of the hidden folder as a "writable overlay"). It is not related to "virtual machine" technology.

Read the full story: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx

Comment: Thanks Martin. It helped. After reading this, I noticed another link that helped in improving my understanding. https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/windows-7/blog/2009/10/02/uac-virtualization-and-how-it-affects-your-installers